# call code behind method from window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I would like execute code behind method **(like save data to database)** from window.onbeforeunload. I cann't use PageMethods because of **non-sharedmembers (txtboxed, cmbboxes etc)** in the save method. How to handle this situation? It is literally killing my time.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do something server related in the `onbeforeunload` event is to make a new request to the server, like using page methods. The page is already on the way to go away, so there is no other way to communicate with the server.

Refactor out the actual saving into a separate static method, that you can call both from the regular events and from the page methods. Example:

```
public static void ActualSave(string somedata, string otherdata) {
  // save
}

public void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string somedata = SomeControl.Text;
  string otherdata = OtherControl.Text;
  ActualSave(somedata, otherdata);
}
```

Comment: ahhh!! I have at least 100 controls data need to save... Thats the reason I am not interested on page methods. Do you have clue for warning user to save data before he is moving from the page, like Yes/No, If YES call code behind method. If NO leave the page.

Comment: @James123: You can display a message to the user and give the option to stay on the page by setting `returnValue`, like: `event.returnValue = 'Warning you have unsaved data.';`. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx